# What is a universal hash function?

Tags: hash, universal-hash

Short and to the point. I'm assuming that it is not a kind of hash function that can be used universally. After having read about universal hash functions used with the one-time pad to form an authentication scheme, these things have bugged me out.

Comment: It is a complicated way of saying that you have a parameter to make the hashing unique. For example if you include a nonce or a key as in HMACs. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing):

> In mathematics and computing universal hashing (in a randomized
>   algorithm or data structure) refers to selecting a hash function at
>   random from a family of hash functions with a certain mathematical
>   property. This guarantees a low number of collisions in expectation,
>   even if the data is chosen by an adversary. Many universal families
>   are known (for hashing integers, vectors, strings), and their
>   evaluation is often very efficient. Universal hashing has numerous
>   uses in computer science, for example in implementations of hash
>   tables, randomized algorithms, and cryptography.

---

**Definition:**
A randomized algorithm $H$ for constructing hash functions $h\colon U \to \{1,\ldots,M\}$
is **universal** if for all $x \neq y$ in $U$, we have
$\Pr_{h\gets H} [h(x) = h(y)] \leq 1/M$

---

From [this answer](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/4987/what-is-universal-hashing?show=4992#a4992):

> Let $\Phi$ be a finite collection of hash functions that map a given
>   universe $U$ of keys into the range $\{0, 1, 2,\ldots, m - 1\}.$
>
> $\Phi$ is called universal if for each pair of distinct keys
>   $x, y \in U$, the number of hash functions $h \in\Phi$ for which
>   $h(x) = h(y)$ is precisely equal to $$\frac{\lvert\Phi\rvert}{m}.$$
>
> With a function randomly chosen from $\Phi$, the chance of a
>   collision between $x$ and $y$ where $x \neq y$ is exactly
>   $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: So can you have a non universal hash function, and if so what would its properties be?  A contra example is always useful to hammer home a point as I'm as bugged out about it as the OP.

Comment: Let's say you have h(x)=x mod m. Then an adversary can choose keys: 1, 1+m, 1+2m, 1+3m etc. They will all cause collisions. But if the function h is chosen randomly from a universal family, you can't guarantee such a "bad" set of keys.